# How to use sweet alert to cofirm image delete for dropify.js?

Tags: javascript, sweetalert, dropify

I want to use sweet alert confirmation before removing image. But, it doesn't work. It works if I use javascript default confirm. I tried using async and await, but it didn't help. How can I fix/debug this?

```
var pathURL = "file_path/";
var dropifyElements = {};
$('.dropify').each(function() {
    dropifyElements[this.id] = true;
});
var drEvent = $('.dropify').dropify();

drEvent.on('dropify.beforeClear', function(event, element) {
    id = event.target.id;
    if(dropifyElements[id]) {
        var x = false;
        return swal({   
            title: "Are you sure?",   
            text: "You will not be able undo this operation!",   
            type: "warning",   
            showCancelButton: true,   
            confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",   
            confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",   
            cancelButtonText: "No, cancel please!",   
            closeOnConfirm: false,   
            closeOnCancel: false 
        }, function(isConfirm){   
            if (isConfirm) {
                x = true;
            } else {     
                swal({
                    title:"Cancelled",
                    text:"Delete Cancelled :)",
                    type:"error",
                    timer: 2000,
                });
                x = true;
            } 
        });
        return x;
        //return confirm("Do you really want to delete this image?");
        // return confirm("Do you really want to delete \"" + element.file.name + "\" ?");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so the `input` element is passed through the event handler so if the user really wants to delete it all you have to do is return false on the handler by default, ***then*** if the user clicks the confirm on the swal instance you just nuke the value of the input element. I don't have your code, but this should work.

```
var pathURL = "file_path/";
var dropifyElements = {};
$('.dropify').each(function() {
    dropifyElements[this.id] = true;
});
var drEvent = $('.dropify').dropify();

drEvent.on('dropify.beforeClear', function(event, element) {
    id = event.target.id;
    if(dropifyElements[id]) {

        swal({   
            title: "Are you sure?",   
            text: "You will not be able undo this operation!",   
            type: "warning",   
            showCancelButton: true,   
            confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",   
            confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",   
            cancelButtonText: "No, cancel please!",   
            closeOnConfirm: false,   
            closeOnCancel: false 
        }, isConfirm => {   
            if (isConfirm) {
                element.value = "";
            } else {     
                swal({
                    title:"Cancelled",
                    text:"Delete Cancelled :)",
                    type:"error",
                    timer: 2000,
                });
            } 
        });

        return false;

    }
});
```

Comment: The problem is, The image is removed even before sweet alert is executed. I need some way to stop the process until user have confirmed.

Comment: Ah I see, one moment

Comment: Editing and using stopPropagation in dropify.min.js does seem to prevent the removal of image. But, then, i am unable to remove it on confirmation.

Comment: @priosshrsth try this now

Comment: It seems to do something. Now, image is not deleted before swal, but it doesn't delete even after confirmation. Thanks a lot for your help though.

Comment: Mabe instead of reseting the element value, use the dropify `clearElement` prototype? And I'm glad to help

Comment: Wow, it worked. Thank you very much. This problem took me my whole day.

Comment: No problem! Glad to help, I know it can be frustrating but keep at it and eventually you'll find the solution! Here's the source for dropify that contains the clearElement prototype: https://github.com/JeremyFagis/dropify/blob/27feaf9bbab4dda682ec5b79166aa6dd19f66164/src/js/dropify.js#L325

Answer (score 0):

I read the answer and don´t work for me, but i write a diferent idea

```
var dropifyElements = {};
$('.dropify').each(function () {
    dropifyElements[this.id] = false;
});

dropElements.on('dropify.beforeClear', function (event, element) {
    id = event.target.id;
    if (!dropifyElements[id]) {
        swal({
            title: "¿Estás seguro?",
            text: "¿Realmente deseas eliminar el archivo \"" + element.file.name + "\" ?",
            icon: "warning",
            buttons: {
                cancel: "Cancelar",
                acept: "Aceptar"
            },
            dangerMode: true
        }).then((action) => {
            if (action == "acept") {
                dropifyElements[id] = true;
                element.clearElement();
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        dropifyElements[id] = false;
        return true;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will also solve the issue on clicking cancel button of sweet-alert pop-up

```
var drEvent = $('.dropify').dropify();

var hideConfirmBox = false;

drEvent.on('dropify.beforeClear', function(event, element){

    if (hideConfirmBox == false) {
        swal({
            title: 'Do you want to remove?',
            text: 'This will remove the selected image.',
            buttons: {
              cancel: true,
              confirm: {
                text: 'Yes, remove it!',
                value: 'proceed'
              }
            },
            dangerMode: true
        }).then((value) => {
            if (value == 'proceed') {
                $("body").trigger("click")
                hideConfirmBox = true;
                $(this).next('button.dropify-clear').trigger('click');
            }
        });
    }


    return hideConfirmBox;
});

drEvent.on('dropify.afterClear', function(event, element){
    hideConfirmBox = false;

    // call ur ajax here for deleting on clicking yes in sweet alert pop-up

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, this will work!

> ```
> dropifyUpload.on('dropify.beforeClear', function (event, element) {
>
>         swal({
>             title: "¿Esta seguro que desea eliminarlo?",
>             text: "¡Una vez confirmado no habrá vuelta atrás!",
>             icon: 'warning',
>             buttons: {
>                 cancel: 'Cancelar',
>                 delete: 'OK'
>             }
>         }).then(function (result) {
>             if (result == "delete") {
>                 element.input.trigger($.Event("dropify.afterClear"), [element]);
>             }
>         })
>
>         return false;
>     });
> ```